# Split string with sublist in python

Tags: python, string, split

I've this string:

```
"{'osFreeMem': 286494720, 'osUpTime': 19230718, 'sysload': [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375], 'nodeUpTime': 1831, 'osTotMem': 536870912, 'nodeMemory': {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760}}"
```

I want to have a dictionary with these values:

```
'osFreeMem': 286494720
'osUpTime': 19230718
'sysload': [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375]    
'nodeUpTime': 1831
'osTotMem': 536870912    
'nodeMemory': {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760}
```

How i can get this list?

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use a JSON parser?

Comment: Where did you get that string from? You could probably get the data directly. If you can't get the data directly, I would switch the single quotes to double and parse it as JSON.

Comment: I get it from a server, by a websocket. How can i parse it with JSON PARSER?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can also use the built in function **eval**

```
>>>d = eval("{'osFreeMem': 286494720, 'osUpTime': 19230718, 'sysload': [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375], 'nodeUpTime': 1831, 'osTotMem': 536870912, 'nodeMemory': {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760}}")
>>>d
{'osFreeMem': 286494720, 'osUpTime': 19230718, 'sysload': [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375], nodeUpTime': 1831, 'osTotMem': 536870912, 'nodeMemory': {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760}}
```

Comment: You can, but you **should not**, because [eval is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: It is dangerous only in case you allow users to hand input to it. Otherwise, it is as dangerous as any other command that might be used to execute commands (such as the commands module)

Comment: thanks. it works!
i just had to do this:
x = ast.literal_eval(message)
result = map(lambda item: item[0] + ': ' + str(item[1]), x.items())

Answer (score 5):

```
In [37]: s = "{'osFreeMem': 286494720, 'osUpTime': 19230718, 'sysload': [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375], 'nodeUpTime': 1831, 'osTotMem': 536870912, 'nodeMemory': {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760}}"

In [38]: import ast

In [39]: d = ast.literal_eval(s)

In [40]: d
Out[40]: 
{'nodeMemory': {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760},
 'nodeUpTime': 1831,
 'osFreeMem': 286494720,
 'osTotMem': 536870912,
 'osUpTime': 19230718,
 'sysload': [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375]}

In [41]: d.items()
Out[41]: 
[('osFreeMem', 286494720),
 ('osUpTime', 19230718),
 ('sysload', [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375]),
 ('nodeUpTime', 1831),
 ('osTotMem', 536870912),
 ('nodeMemory', {'heapTotal': 8766304, 'heapUsed': 7789588, 'rss': 22773760})]
```

or

```
In [44]: import json

In [45]: json.loads(s.replace("'",'"')).items()
Out[45]: 
[(u'osFreeMem', 286494720),
 (u'osUpTime', 19230718),
 (u'sysload', [0.24609375, 0.62109375, 0.734375]),
 (u'nodeUpTime', 1831),
 (u'osTotMem', 536870912),
 (u'nodeMemory', {u'heapTotal': 8766304, u'heapUsed': 7789588, u'rss': 22773760})]
```

Comment: +1 for `literal_eval` - not convinced about replacing quotes and using `json` though